# ANR While calling a method of adapter class

Tags: java, android

I am trying to retrieve the row_count of a table from SQLite. The code, which I used to do this task is freezing my application. This is entirely run on back-end, nothing is there in the MainUI thread. But, also I am getting ANR error.

This is my code, where I am calling the method -

```
public class del_person extends Activity{
String[] images = {}; 

 @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.del_person);
        final adapter info = new adapter(this);

   //     new del_person_Dup(null).execute();

        new Task(info).execute((Void)null);
 }
}



class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
String[] images = {}; 
adapter mAdapter; 

Task(adapter adapter)  {
   mAdapter = adapter;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
  // the code from the Runnable using the mAdapter instead of info.


    Log.v("distinctrowcount() is:",""+mAdapter.distinctrowcount()+"");
    Log.v("started del_person.java","started del_person.java");

    for (int i=0;i<mAdapter.distinctrowcount();i++)

{
        Log.v ("This is the "+i+"th iteration","This is the "+i+"th iteration");
    images[i] =mAdapter.getPersonList(i+1); 
    Log.v("Persons",images[i]);
}

return null;
}
}
```

I also tried using AsyncTask for this. But also, I am unable to come out of this.

Here is my distinctrowcount() from adapter class:

adapter.java:

```
public int distinctrowcount()
{
    int rc = 0;
    try {
        open();
        rc = mDbHelper.getdistinctrc();
        close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rc;
}
```

helper.java - getdistinctrc():

```
public int getdistinctrc() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        SQLiteDatabase myDB;            
        int values = 0;
        int distinct_count = 0;
         try {
              myDB=this.openDataBase();                   
              Cursor c=myDB.rawQuery("select count (DISTINCT FileName) from Photos;",null);
              if (c != null ) {

                          String h = "";
                          while(c.moveToFirst()){
                              distinct_count = c.getInt(0);
                             //   h = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COUNT(*)"));
                            }

                     } 


                  if(c != null)
                 {
                         c.close();
                     myDB.close();

                  }                    
                  }catch(SQLException sqle){

                  throw sqle;

                  }
         return distinct_count;  
    }
```

AsyncTask code:

```
class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String[] images = {}; 
    adapter mAdapter; 

    Task(adapter adapter)  {
       mAdapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      // the code from the Runnable using the mAdapter instead of info.


        Log.v("distinctrowcount() is:",""+mAdapter.distinctrowcount()+"");
        Log.v("started del_person.java","started del_person.java");

        for (int i=0;i<mAdapter.distinctrowcount();i++)

    {
            Log.v ("This is the "+i+"th iteration","This is the "+i+"th iteration");
        images[i] =mAdapter.getPersonList(i+1); 
        Log.v("Persons",images[i]);
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

Is there any other better way to implement this, other than Runnable() and AsyncTask? Please help me with some sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And where exactly are you running that method on a background thread? In your code you just declare a `Runnable` object and immediately call its `run()` method directly.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Luksprog, I just want to run a for loop (which I have in the run() method), where I'll display log messages. Thats what I want my code to do.

Comment: Then remove the `Runnable` and use an `AsyncTask` and call that method in the `doInBackground()` method.

Comment: @Luksprog, I tried it, but I am getting syntactical errors, I am a newbie to android. If you don't mind, can you please show me, how to implement the same loop in AsyncTask, by modifying my code, if possible? please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code doesn't run those database queries on a background thread. Use an `AsyncTask` instead like this:

```
static class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    adapter mAdapter; 

    Task(adapter adapter)  {
       mAdapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      // the code from the Runnable using the mAdapter instead of info.
    return null;
}
```

And in the `Activity`'s `onCreate()` you'll use something like:

```
new Task(info).execute((Void)null);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Luksprog, how can I create `info` variable here?

Comment: @nki `info` is the variable that you currently create in the `onCreate()` method. Pass it to the `AsyncTask`.

Comment: the application is not freezing now, but I could not post the log message `Log.v("Persons",images[i]);` in the `for` loop?? Can't AsyncTask post log messages?

Comment: @nki The `AsyncTask` can post Log message. Do you get in the logcat the `Log.v("distinctrowcount() is:",""+info.distinctrowcount()+"");` line? If yes, how many values do you get?

Comment: I did not get that line @Luksprog.

Comment: @nki Can you post the new code you have with the `AsyncTask`? If you put a log entry in the constructor of the `AsyncTask` it appears?

Comment: @nki Did you also add the last line from my answer `new Task(info).execute((Void)null);` in your `onCreate` method?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37888/discussion-between-nki-and-luksprog)